# Can you use/interchange the same Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 sd-card in a Raspberry Pi 4 and a Raspberry Pi 5?

Tags: pi-4, sd-card, ubuntu, pi-5

I have both a Raspberry Pi 4 and a Raspberry Pi 5, and I am wondering if it is safe and successful to use a Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 formatted SD-Card between the two (ie. use it in the rpi4 for a while, power it off, use it in the rpi5 for a while, power it off, use it in the rpi4 for a while, etc.).

So far I've been using different sd cards between them.

Comment: What is keeping you from trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with an SD card I've been using Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 on a Raspberry Pi 5 on, and put it in a Raspberry Pi 400 and had no issues.